# Cannot remove a Wordpress cron job from an empty app on Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

We installed Wordpress on GAE to test the performance and decided to remove it after all. It was linked to a Bitbucket install and an empty version was deployed to remove Wordpress. However, even if the latest build being pushed has zero files (other than index.php & app.yaml), a wp-cron.php file runs every 15min.

I also cannot turn off GAE as a service because our Firebase apps rely on it for some reason. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the cron.yaml file so that it only contains `cron:` and redeploy it ([source](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron))

Comment: Amazing, that did it! Thank you!